# How do I have multiple filter boxes associated to specific charts on a single dashboard in Apache Superset?

Tags: apache-superset

I have created a dashboard in Apache Superset that I would like to have 6 different charts on. For 2 of the charts, I would like one set of filter boxes to be applicable, for the next 2 charts, another set of filter boxes, and for the last 2 charts, a final set of filter boxes. Is this possible?

Or can I add filter boxes to the chart itself like you can do with Tableau?